# Big iPhone 5 Simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I was messing with the instruments panel on my application. The 4 inch retina simulator was working fine and used to look exactly like the iPhone 5:

[image]

However, when I was messing with the automation, 4 inch retina simulator changed and now looks pretty much like a very long iPad:

[image]

(sorry for the very big image but this is the actual size of it now).

And now whenever I want to bring up the simulator, it continues to look like this one above. I am sure that there is an easy fix to this and that is why I ask because I honestly don't want to have to re install Xcode 4.5

Thanks!

Comment: You have revealed the top secret future iPad4 design :)

Comment: Weird... my simulators always look like big ipads, with the exception of the iphone non-retina.

Comment: @TomIrving It is a programming question. It's just not a programming _language_ question. Let's not be pedantic anyway. I ran into the same issue when XCode upgraded on me suddenly and it was blocking my ability to continue _programming_. The same trajectory to this page will be followed by countless others, no doubt. Not only did the original answer help me a bit, but I also added my own when I worked out the problem. Summary: I had a problem with my programming tool, I went to SO - other people had the same, I got help, I (hopefully) helped others => SO is great. Stop trying to "fix" it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When the Simulator is active, go to Window > Size > 50%.

You can also change the size by using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

**EDIT:**

When you're using a retina MBP, the Simulator will take advantage of that and go into retina mode as well, which will be the same size as the regular Simulator (just like with the real devices). Since it's the same size it can use the slightly bigger border and look like the actual device, instead of using the thin iPad-like border.

On a "normal resolution" display, only the non-retina iPhone simulator will use the iPhone border.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, However I have tried that and all it does is make the scaling of the screen smaller. But, it keeps this iPad look and feel to it. I know it's not that big of a deal but I kinda thought it was cool to have the actual iPhone on there.

Comment: I think only the non-retina iPhone Simulator at 100% shows up as an actual iPhone. The iPad or the retina iPhone simulators look like an iPad.

Comment: Strange.. I wonder why mine looked like the one above before?

Comment: @Zack what's the version of your Max OX? (Or rMBP?)

Comment: @Kjuly I have also discovered something more interesting.. I have a Thunderbolt external monitor hooked up with my computer. When I drag the simulator to the external it changes to the iPad looking one. When I drag it back over to my laptop it changes back to the simulator like the one in my answer. Strange..

Comment: @Zack Do you have a retina MBP?

Comment: @Kjuly correct. You think it can sense that I do have retina?

Comment: @Zack yep, I think it shows differently depend on your screen solution.

Comment: Yes. On retina MBPs it will go into retina mode.

Comment: Thank you all for helping figure it out

Answer (score 0):

The reason this changed is that your upgrade to XCode 5 brought with it the iOS7 Simulator and dropped the older emulator you were using.

DrummerB's answer above will rein in the size of the simulator, but it won't bring back the black bezel and your app won't look the same.  To see what you were seeing before, do this:

1. At the top left of the XCode window you will see the project (or "target") name and the selected simulator. Like "MyProgram > iPhone Retina (4-inch)". Click on "iPhone Retina..."
2. A droplist will appear with the title "iOS Device" at the top. At the bottom you will see "More Simulators...". Click that option.
3. This brings up the preferences dialog on the "Download" page where you can install extra components in XCode. Select "iOS 6.1 Simulator" and it will start to download.
   It's about half a gig, so it will take some time.
4. When it finishes it will throw a dialog asking you to restart XCode - go ahead.
5. Now back in XCode, go to the iOS Device choice again, and this time select one of the "iOS 6" options.

You'll get back what you had before - the black iPhone-4ish device.

(If you followed DrummerB's advice above, it might look tiny now, so go to Window->Scale in the iOS Simulator and select 100%)

Also note, that you probably want to use the iOS7 simulator at some point too, since is showing you what your app will look like on a lot of users' iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think there may be a bug in the simulator code or in the interface builder or somewhere...

I have two storyboards (iphone/ipad) and a nib for a table cell. 
My simulated display looked completely as expected until I changed some autoresizing values in the nib. Then suddenly, the simulator started showing the giant/ipad like view for the iPhone Retina 3.5 display. Also when I re-oriented the hardware in the simulator, it actually showed the entire device landscape. A little while later I changed a table in my storyboard from grouped to plain and then the simulator looked fine again. I just changed some autoresizing values again and it is back to the giant iPhone.

I wonder if it is related to auto-resizing/auto-layout. On my nibs, I have auto-layout turned off, but I on my storyboard it is turned on.